# MySQL Query results AND

Tags: mysql, sql

What I have is 3 tables: `fruits`, `categories` and `fruit_category`

`fruits`:

```
fruit_id | fruit_name
1          apple
2          orange
3          mango
4          banana
5          lanzones
6          pineapple
```

`fruit_category`:

```
fruit_id | cat_id
1          1
2          9
3          7
4          7
5          8
6          9
1          9
2          7
3          9
4          1
5          3
6          5
```

`categories`

```
cat_id | cat_name
1        one
2        two
3        three
4        four
5        five
6        six
7        seven
8        eight
9        nine
```

When I execute a query looking for fruits that are either in categories 7 or 9 I get the correct results

```
fruit_name
apple
orange
mango
banana
pineapple
```

But when I use the `AND` operator, I always get 0 results. Below is my query for AND (same for OR)

```
SELECT `o`.`fruit_name`
FROM   `fruits` AS `o`
       JOIN `fruit_category` AS `oc`
         ON `o`.`fruit_id` = `oc`.`fruit_id`
       JOIN `categories` AS `c`
         ON `c`.`cat_id` = `oc`.`cat_id`
WHERE  `oc`.`cat_id` = 7
       AND `oc`.`cat_id` = 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use logical *or* (one value can't be equal to two unequal values at the same time), represented by `in` here:

```
where `oc`.`cat_id` in ( 7, 9)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
where `oc`.`cat_id` = 7 or `oc`.`cat_id` = 9
```

If you want to ensure, that `fruit_name` is in both categories, you should use `group by` and `having` clauses after the `where` (*that is represented above, with `or`*):

```
group by `o`.`fruit_name`
having count(distinct `oc`.`cat_id`) = 2
```

Comment: thanks. yielded same result for OR which is correct but main problem is when using AND

Comment: @badboy: you should read the answer above one more time, mainly the part on round brackets.

Comment: To clarify are you looking for a fruit that is in both category 7 and 9? You would still use an OR because as pointed out above the cat_id can't be both at the same time. But you would then use a having clause to count the number of categories it is in and choose those that are in both.

Comment: hmm... I used your code for the OR results and it gave me the correct answer for OR, which is great. but what's the query for AND. the result for AND is what I can't get my head around with

Comment: Yes @Niagaradad . Can you give an example query for that?

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  o.fruit_name 
FROM 
  fruits as o 
JOIN 
  fruit_category as oc 
ON 
  o.fruit_id = oc.fruit_id 
JOIN 
  categories as c 
ON 
  c.cat_id = oc.cat_id 
WHERE 
  oc.cat_id IN (7,9)
GROUP BY
  o.fruit_name
HAVING
  COUNT(oc.cat_id) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you. You both had the perfect answer.